# Waypoint not working on overflow:hidden;

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-waypoints

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BgV6b/)**

If you remove `overflow` property from `.wrapper` in fiddle, waypoints will work fine.

But not with `overflow` `hidden` in `x` or `y`

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="sec1" class="section">dfa fdasfsdafd as</div>
    <div id="sec2" class="section">dfa fdasfsdafd as</div>
    <div id="sec3" class="section">dfa fdasfsdafd as</div>
    <div id="sec4" class="section">dfa fdasfsdafd as</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, .wrapper, .section{
    height:100%;
}
.wrapper{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#sec3').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $('#sec3').css({
        backgroundColor: "#f99"
    });
});
```

Any jQuery or css solution?

Comment: You need to post code here that reproduces the issue.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Archer He posted a fiddle. LOL

Comment: Yeah but for the sake of legal issues :p, i have added the code

Comment: I don't get it why peoples would just down vote for no reason?

Comment: Or at least, don't state the reason... I've up-voted to counteract one.

Comment: @JamieBarker I know he posted a fiddle, LOL.  He needs to **post code here** to reproduce the issue, as per the link I posted.

Comment: @Archer But the Fiddle reproduces the issue *facepalm*

Comment: @JamieBarker The code should be posted here.  The link is fine but makes this page useless if jsfiddle is down.  Questions and answers should be self contained enough to make Stack Overflow work without external resources.  You've not been here long so I won't be as rude as to say *facepalm*.  Please don't resort to a childish attitude.  This site is not like that.

Comment: @Archer I think i will agree, I will make sure to post the code next time thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Imran - I've removed my -1 now.  It's not personal when people downvote.  It's just to let other people know that the question may not be of value, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED 2014-05-16**

Add a `waypoint()` function binded to the `<div>` id to make the css changes appear.

The context of the `waypoint()` should be your outer div `<div class="wrapper">`:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BgV6b/6/)**

Comment: Thanks @urbz -- If i am correct what you are doing here is refreshing waypoint function each time a user scroll in that div...?

Comment: Glad to help! :) The `scroll()` function executes the `waypoint()` function when you reach that element, since you specified what `<div>` it should change styling for.

Comment: @urbz - No words to say , Amazing

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but the scroll thing sounds like a disaster waiting to happen, initiating hundreds of waypoints each time you scroll. You should be using the `context` option to make the scrollable element waypoints listens to the wrapper instead of the body.

Comment: @imakewebthings You are right, i used `context` method & the performance difference was 200% **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BgV6b/5/)**

Comment: @urbz please read the above 2 comments and change your answer with this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BgV6b/5/)** in case any one else visited this question, he should get the more performance oriented answer.