# jQuery "waypoints" doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-waypoints

I am loading "jquery.waypoints.min.js" (seems to load correctly when i look with network analysis tool), but nothing happens with this simple script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#footer').waypoint(function() {
       $('body').addClass("foo");
    });
});
```

I am trying for hours now ...

Btw. i am loading all my scripts per functions-php in wordpress:

```
function add_js_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('waypoints', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js_scripts');
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your javascript console? You could add `console.log("running script");` to the start of the script, then "running script" should show up in console if the script is actually running.

Comment: accidental duplicate of [How to make jQuery waypoints plugin fire when an element is in view and not scrolled past?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497122/how-to-make-jquery-waypoints-plugin-fire-when-an-element-is-in-view-and-not-scro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waypoints run when you scroll **past** an element. This can never happen with the footer, as it will always be on the page. You can add an offset to work around this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#footer').waypoint(function() {
       $('body').addClass("foo");
    }, { offset: 'bottom-in-view' });
});
```

The waypoint will now run when the bottom of the footer element is within view. You could also set offset to `'100%'` to run if *any* of the footer element is in view.

Comment: No this doesn't help. Also added some line-breaks after #footer - still nothing happens.

Comment: @HenningFischer Are you sure? Seems to be working with that code. When I scroll to the bottom of the page, the `foo` css class is added to body. Did you want something else to happen?

Comment: Whooops now it works i think i had to clear the cache, THX a lot! Also i think i have to work with "inview.js" when i want to trigger a function if the top of an objects hits the viewport.

Comment: @HenningFischer what about `offset: '100%'`? That should trigger when the top of the footer hits the bottom of the window.

Comment: Wow cool, i think i had a misunderstanding about how waypoints really works.

Comment: You should really check out getting started page, everything is really well documented and explained.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#footer').waypoint(function() {
        handler: function(direction) {
            $('body').addClass("foo");
        },
        offset: '90%'
    });
});
```

Check out the [Getting started page](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/).

Comment: Seems that there's a typo, `90%` should be in quotes.

Comment: True, I was hasty and forgot the quotations. Thanks :)